# jQuery: show / hide Div when first or second radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I am new to jQuery and hope someone here can help me with this.

I am trying to **show / hide a div** (`'requestDetails'`) **if the first OR second of a** variable **range of radio buttons is selected** (the reason for this is that I would like to avoid hard-coding specific values to check for).

So far I only have a hard-coded solution but this doesn't work properly and I am not sure about how to address only the first and second radio button without this.

I tried to avoid using IDs or further classes on the radio buttons to reduce code but can add this if recommended.

**My jQuery:**

```
$('[name=requestType]').on('change', function(){
    if( ($('[name=requestType]').val() == 'value1') || ($('[name=requestType]').val() == 'value2') ){
        $('#requestDetails').show();
    }else{
        $('#requestDetails').hide();
    }
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="requestType" value="value1" />Value1  
<input type="radio" name="requestType" value="value2" />Value2  
<input type="radio" name="requestType" value="value3" />Value3  
// ...
<div id="requestDetails" class="hidden"> ... </div>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help, 
Mike

Comment: You have an element with the '#requestDetails' id in the page, right?

Comment: @adamjld: yes, sure - it is just a simple div with that ID which is why I didnt post it here. - <div id="requestDetails" class="hidden"> ... </div>

Comment: It's a good idea to post all relevant code so people don't have to ask the silly questions :)

Comment: @adamjld: agree - sorry ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would identify the buttons you would like to use as triggers for this show/hide event with a new class. Then attach the event to this class of button. This does not add much in code overhead.

Example:

```
<input type="radio" class="special" name="requestType" value="value1" />Value1  
<input type="radio" class="special" name="requestType" value="value2" />Value2  
<input type="radio" name="requestType" value="value3" />Value3  


$('.special').on('change', function(){
    if( ($('[name=requestType]').val() == 'value1') || ($('[name=requestType]').val() == 'value2') ){
        $('#requestDetails').show();
    }else{
        $('#requestDetails').hide();
    }
});
```

This will result in button 1 and button 2 affecting the div with id=requestDetails, while button 3 or any others without the class will not.

Comment: Thanks for this ! - I like the class approach but am still looking for a way to avoid calling specific values in the code (see my comment above). Any ideas for that too ?

Comment: I am not sure how you are generating the buttons. when they are generated do you have logic knowing if this button will affect the DIV or not? I may not be totally clear on the use case here but if you have logic in place to understand which buttons will affect the DIV upon creation, why not just add the special class to those buttons when generated?

Comment: I found a way to achieve what I wanted by using .hasClass - your suggestion with the class pointed me in the right direction ! Thanks for that - issue resolved. :) - ...if($(this).hasClass('triggerDiv')){ ... } ...

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$('[name=requestType]').on('change', function () {

    $('#requestDetails').toggle((this.value == 'value1' || this.value == 'value2'));

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cwahL1tz/8/)

Comment: Come on SO Bala. We expect more from you

Comment: @JqueryKing unagal asirvatham eruntha pothum

Comment: Thanks for this, Bala ! - Is there a way I can achieve the same without actually stating specific values, so just by saying the first or second radio of that range ? The buttons are created dynamically which is why I would prefer this solution.

Comment: @keewee279  as i understand  you dont want to check value.  is it correct ? . then u can use index like $(this).index()

Answer (score 0):

With no hardcoding, use the parent containing the inputs and use :nth-child selector. See jsfiddle for example :

```
$('[name=requestType]').on('change', function () {
    if($('#parent input:nth-child(2)').val() == $(this).val() ||$('#parent input:nth-child(3)').val() == $(this).val())
    $('#requestDetails').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cwahL1tz/11/

Also made one with the exact behavior you wan to obtain : http://jsfiddle.net/cwahL1tz/13/